# Circuit of a voltage divider in a transmission line?

Tags: voltage-divider, transmission-line

How does a (resistive) voltage divider in a transmission line work?

Until now I only found a circuit on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#Resistive_divider that treats a transmission line in very simplified manner (e.g. without showing the two conductive parts of such a line). 
The voltage divider I have in mind is a 1:100 tap-off, branched behind a pulse generator. The middle connection of the tap-off is connected to an oscilloscope to measure the applied voltage.
I would like to understand how the voltage is divided using this real divider and why there is no reflection from the high impedance (middle) connection.

Comment: You should probably be searching on the term *rf attenuator* rather than *resistor divider*. However, like a lot of things in rf, best practice is a matter of black art and trade secrets, so there isn't as much information available publicly as you might like.

Comment: I wouldn't say "trade secrets" but rather "400 dollar, 2000 page long books of math"

Comment: Are you asking about an ideal voltage divider? Or a real voltage divider? And _where_ is it placed in the transmission line? And what are you trying to accomplish? And what is connected to the middle of the voltage divider? Please add a good amount of context/clarification.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I tried to add more context to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In controlled impedance situations, you normally don't use classical resistive dividers, but [Pi-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A0_pad) or [T-style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T_pad) attenuators, sometimes also called "Pads".

If the characteristic impedances of the ports are not the same, [L-pads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_pad) can also be used.

Essentially, your examples shows a L-pad. The problem that happens here is that the impedances are not matched, and reflections can occur at the transition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case (of a 1:100-ratio of the output voltages) I was indeed wondering why there's no reflection or how this is taken into account to achieve this ratio.